# Pythonでsortした際のエラーについて

Tags: python, sympy, sort

以下の、test.pyというファイルを実行したところ、エラーが出ます。
sort()の行でエラーが出ているようですが、原因は何でしょうか？

また、配列内の要素に虚数が含まれている条件でsortする方法はありますでしょうか？

**test.py**

```
    import sys, json
    sys.path.append('/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
    from sympy import *

    x=Symbol('x')

    #数値が文字列化された配列
    str=['-1/4 + sqrt(15)*I/12', '-(135/64 + 15*sqrt(6)/16)**(1/3)/3 - 1/4 + 5/(16*(135/64 + 15*sqrt(6)/16)**(1/3))']
    #数値型に変換
    list = [sympify(v) for v in str]
    #並べ替え
    list.sort()
```

**実行結果**

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    list.sort()
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 334, in __lt__
    raise TypeError("Invalid comparison of complex %s" % me)
TypeError: Invalid comparison of complex -1/4 + sqrt(15)*I/12
```

Windows上に、VitualBoxとVagrantでUbuntuの仮想環境を作って実行しています。

使用しているPythonのバージョンは `python --version`で調べたところ、2.7.6です。`python3 --version`だと、Python 3.4.3が表示されます。
　Homebrewのインストール等がうまくいかず、バージョンを新しいものに切り替えないまま使用しています。

虚数単位*I*が文字列中に含まれているのは、このプログラムの範囲外でのSympyモジュールの計算結果として出てきたものです。意図的に書いたものではないですが、他のプログラムの実行中にも虚数が出てくる可能性はあると思います。

Comment: __Invalid comparison of complex__ は、「複素数の比較は不正」ってことですね。`I`が入っているせいで、sympy的に複素数と扱っているようです。意図的に複素数を使用しているのでしょうか?(だとしたら、Takayuki SHIMIZUKAWA さんの回答にあるように比較不可能。)それとも何かのタイプミスでしょうか?

Comment: 質問の趣旨からは外れますが、例えば絶対値(absolute value)でソートするのであれば `lst.sort(key=lambda x: Abs(x))` とすれば良いかと。別の基準でソートしたい場合は key パラメータの lambda 式を適宜変更する事になります。

Comment: 「虚数が出てくる可能性はある」と言うことでしたら、比較不可能ですから、metropolis さんの書かれたように絶対値とか、あるいは実数部とか偏角とか(普通しないかな…)とにかく比較可能な基準を決めてやらないとソートはできないですね。何を基準にソートしたいんですか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sympify` した結果のオブジェクトが大小比較不可能なためではないでしょうか。